# how to test a function dependent on document global?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I want to start writing unit tests for my code. I thought I'd start with a nice and simple function.

string => string

in action here: http://jsbin.com/yufuzawalo/edit?js,console,output

```
const animEndString = (type = 'transition') => {
    let types =
        type === 'transition'
            ? {
                OTransition: 'oTransitionEnd',
                WebkitTransition: 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                MozTransition: 'transitionend',
                transition: 'transitionend'
            }
            : {
                OAnimation: 'oAnimationEnd',
                WebkitAnimation: 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                MozAnimation: 'animationend',
                animation: 'animationend'
            }

    const elem = document.createElement('div')

    return Object.keys(types).reduce(function(prev, trans) {
        return undefined !== elem.style[trans] ? types[trans] : prev
    }, '')
}
```

And the test:

```
describe('example', () => {
    it('should return animationend when passed the string animation', () => {
        const value = animationEnd('animation')

        expect(value).toBe('animationend')
    })

    it('should return transitionEnd when passed the string animation', () => {
        const value = animationEnd('transition')

        expect(value).toBe('transitionend')
    })
})
```

output:

```
example › should return transitionEnd when passed the string animation

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected value to be:
      "transitionend"
    Received:
```

The test is failing as an empty string is being returned.  <del>I'm presuming that Jest doesn't know what to do with `document.createElement('fake')`</del>

How would I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved...

I've added the following to my setup-jest file

```
global.document.createElement = jest.fn(() => ({
    style: {
        transition: 'opacity 300ms ease',
        animation: 'test 300ms'
    }
}))
```